# Just increase the size of math symbols

Tags: exam

I want enlarge the "only math symbols" for the all document. But how?

My code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\firstpageheader{Sample Exam (\numpoints\ points)\\ September 26, 2019}{}{Name: \underline{\hspace{2.5in}}}
\runningheader{Sample Exam}{}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningheadrule

\begin{document}
\begin{questions} 

\fullwidth{\emph{Math mode} is used to display $x+y$ mathematical content in \LaTeX, and there are two main forms of math mode $x^2-y^2$: \emph{display mode} and \emph{inline mode}.  Question~\ref{DisplayModeExample} uses \emph{display mode}, which centers the math $sinx-2x$ content on its own line.  Question~\ref{InlineModeExample} uses \emph{inline mode} to render the math content within a line of text.}

\question[10] \label{DisplayModeExample}
Find an equation for the tangent line to the following curve at the point (0,1).
\[2xy^3 + y^4 = 1 + x^3y\]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Since your question is rather simple, you could easily provide a much simpler minimal working examples (MWE). `;-)`

Comment: why are you using `$\displaystyle...$`  rather than `\[....\]` ?

Comment: @Gaussler i edited the code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm a bit of a novice so:)

Comment: If you use `\[` then probably you will not want to increase the size of the math (inline math will look very weird if 1 that happens to be in math is larger than 1 than is in text.) (such as your (0,1) coordinate in the new example)

Comment: I want to enlarge a little, how about the code? I wondered:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default at normalsize for the `11pt` option is

```
 \DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{10.95}{8}{6}
```

that is, if the text font is 10.95pt use 10.95pt in math text size, 8pt in scripts and 6pt in scriptscript size

So before:

[image]

after:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[11pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\firstpageheader{Sample Exam (\numpoints\ points)\\ September 26, 2019}{}{Name: \underline{\hspace{2.5in}}}
\runningheader{Sample Exam}{}{Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\runningheadrule

     \DeclareMathSizes{10.95}{15}{12}{10}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions} 

\fullwidth{\emph{Math mode} is used to display $x+y$ mathematical content in \LaTeX, and there are two main forms of math mode $x^2-y^2$: \emph{display mode} and \emph{inline mode}.  Question~\ref{DisplayModeExample} uses \emph{display mode}, which centers the math $sinx-2x$ content on its own line.  Question~\ref{InlineModeExample} uses \emph{inline mode} to render the math content within a line of text.}

\question[10] \label{DisplayModeExample}
Find an equation for the tangent line to the following curve at the point (0,1).
\[2xy^3 + y^4 = 1 + x^3y\]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I left it but never `$sin x$` always use `$\sin x$`

Comment: Thanks! I guess most Tex users does not know this simple but useful command

Comment: You are right sir. I should have used ```$\sin x$```. Thank you very much for your helps:)

Comment: @BlackMild actually I would never use it as here increasing the main textstyle font to be larger than the surrounding text. Its main use is for setting up alternative font sets some of which can not allow the script styles to get so small and remain readable (Computer modern small sizes have a lot of care to vary the shapes to maintain legibility) so using it with the first two arguments unchanged but larger values for the 2nd and 3rd arguments is quite common.

Comment: I knew the command, but couldn't figure out the meaning of the first argument.  Thanks!

Comment: for ```documentclass[10pt]``` ```\DeclareMathSizes{9.95}{14}{11}{9}``` is not working. What should I do?

Comment: for `[10pt]`  the textsize is 10pt so the first argument should be `{10}` @suarez

Comment: Yes it makes sense. Thanks